# Скрипт не узнает переменную

Tags: php

Как заставить определит переменную: например, этот код не работает у меня:

HTML code:

```
<form action = "http://localhost/PHP/chapt2/switch.php" method="get">
    number: <input type="text" name="number"/><br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

php скрипт:

```
    <?
switch($number)
{
    case 1:
      echo ("one ");
    case 2: case 3:
      echo ("free");
    case 4: case 5:
      echo ("five");
    case 6: case 7:
      echo ("seven");
    case 8: case 9:
      echo ("nine");
    break;
    default:       
      echo ("This isn't number or number is > 9 or < 1");
} ?>
```

А оно мне всегда возвращает дефолтное значение.

Comment: А что такое $number в PHP-коде и откуда оно берётся? Если вы думаете, что значение $number будет автоматически подставлено из HTML-формы, то, хвала всевышнему, в вашем случае это не так :) Изучайте документацию на предмет $_GET, $_POST и прочих полезностей.

Comment: Думаю, будет интересно http://php.net/manual/ru/security.globals.php

Answer (score 6):

```
switch($_GET['number']){
   // и т.д.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`switch($number)` замени на `switch($_GET['number'])`

Answer (score 3):

Я комиксом, ради  .... просто ради... уж развеселило.

Новая история.

```
Скрипт не узнает переменную

switch($number)
```

*ругаясь* **$number** ты кто такой? Откуда ты?

**$number** я $number я просто хочу познакомиться и правильно с тобой дружить!

В игру вступает 
    form action

Рубят вы там попробуйте уже подружиться то! А то я устала отправлять вам данные, а вы их никак не можете принять

**$number** как это не можем, я же **$number** я же принимаю от тебя

```
<input type="text" name="number"/>
```

Нет не принимаешь отчетил **form action**. с которым согласился **switch**.

На помощь пришли **GLOBALS**!

"Эй ребят!", сказал массив **$_GET**, "У меня для вас новость! Получите свою переменную от меня!"

Но как, спросил недоуменно **$number**?

ДА просто, ответил массив.

Поставь после себя знак **=** и присвой от меня нужное значение.

```
$number=$_GET['number'];
```

switch теперь и ты можешь правильно сработать вместе с новым другом, у которого теперь есть смысл существовать как настоящая переменная!

**Так и подружились $_GET $number switch и form**

ps спасибо за внимание

Comment: Минутка наркомании на хешкоде? :)

Comment: по ходу дела да :)